# updating existing text for ProgressBar.js circle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, progress-bar

I am using ProgressBar.js to create a circle with a percentage in the center. The circle creates properly but when I run it again, I want it to update the text (the percentage) with the new passed in value.

How can I do this? Currently, the code does not update the inner text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`circle.animate(value)`](https://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/#animateprogress-options-cb) or [`circle.set(value)`](https://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/#setprogress):

```js
let circle = null

/**
 * @param percentage - decimal from 0 to 1 (0.7 => 70%)
 */
function refreshCircle(percentage) {
  if (!circle) {
    circle = /* initialize */
  }

  circle.animate(percentage)

  // or without animation:
  circle.set(percentage)
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vupc9b73/)